# Efficiently performance Graph Contraction based on a criteria

Tags: graph

I have a directed weighted simple graph. I want to contract every node that has equal node value with another node that is directly connected to it. After contraction parallel edges would be made into one with the sum of the weights.

What is the most efficient way/algorithm for doing this? My graph is stored as an adjacency list if that would alter the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to create a new graph and do not want to do this inplace, maybe a union-find data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure would help you here.

This structure to allow you to define a representative vertex for each set of vertices that get merged together. The you create your new graph on this set of vertices and use the union-find structure to to create the edges on this new graph.